# javascript:why anonymous function passed as argument cant access "this" in object?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I have this code:

```
function Const(val)
{   
    this.value = val;
    this.meth = function()
    {   
        var self = this;
        function rfunc()
        {
            console.log(self);
        }
        rfunc()
    }   
}
var obj = new Const("test");
obj.meth();
```

and the result is:

> Const {value: "test"};

but when I try this code:

```
function Const(val)
{   
    this.value = val;
    this.meth = function(callback)
    {   
        var self = this;
        callback();
    }   
}

var obj = new Const("test");
obj.meth(function(){
console.log(self);
});
```

the result is:

> Window object.

I expect that the result would be like first example. Why has this happened?

I know that when I change code to:

```
function Const(val)
{   
    this.value = val;
    this.meth = function(callback)
    {   
        //var self = this;
        callback.call(this);
    }   
}

var obj = new Const("test");
obj.meth(function(){
console.log(this);
});
```

then the result is like first example...

Comment: You're a little confused about where variables are declared and accessible. The reason you get the window is because you used the name [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) for the variable, had you used any other name, it would be `undefined`.

Comment: Your title is misleading. The function can't access `self`, not `this`.

Comment: @adeneo but when i remove self and pass this argument in example 2
result is the samn

Comment: In the third example you're using `call` to explicitly set the `this` value, that's completely different. In the first example `self` is within scope, and it's accessible. In the middle example you define a variable inside a function, and expect that variable to be accessible anywhere else.

Comment: @melpomene when you use this rather than self result is same

Comment: @sami No it's not. `self` is a variable reference. `this` is a reference to the calling context.

Comment: `window.self` is a property itself. `window` object has a property `self`. From MDN  *The Window.self read-only property returns the window itself, as a WindowProxy. It can be used with dot notation on a window object (that is, window.self) or standalone (self).*. So in your case, you are able to see `window` because you are referring to the self variable which is a predefined property.